# Cron curl on AWS EC2

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

Complete newbie with AWS and relative newbie with bash. I want to set up a quick pull-and-append call every 10 minutes to a small text file on the NYC site that contains some real-time traffic data that I want.

The command `curl --silent http://[IP.stuff.nyc_traffic_data].txt >> data.txt` does exactly what I want it to. So, I created cron.txt with the contents

```
*/10 * * * * curl --silent http://[IP.stuff.nyc_traffic_data].txt >> data.txt
```

`crontab cron.txt` doesn't throw any obvious errors, but I don't seem to be able to get data.txt to update.

What am I missing? (Have done the usual research to find an answer, but I think the problem here is that I don't know what I don't know, as it were.)

Thanks!

Comment: `...  >> /path/to/data.txt` ?

Comment: you also may have different env vars that might impact your cron + make sure it'a full path as suggested in comment above ^^

Comment: File permissions on existing file might prohibit overwriting from the `cron` job? Try deleting the file created outside of `cron`. (But I do like the @dusan.bajic's idea of using a full path.)

Comment: You don't add user: `*/10 * * * * root curl --silent http://[IP.stuff.nyc_traffic_data].txt >> data.txt`

Comment: Dusan's comment did it - since I didn't specify a path, `cron` created a new file in my home. (Duh.) Turns out it's been running just fine this whole time. Thanks for the other comments - looks like the EC2 instance does give the rights necessary to interact with `cron`, but I don't have root access, I think. Like I said, still learning. Thanks all!